# Using Bray-Curtis distance for association rules

Tags: r, distance, association-rules

may be some one has this Experience:

I would like to find cannbalization in a transactions. I have read [this](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40745-014-0011-y) nice essay P.29-30 it says that we could use Bray-Curtis distance to find cannibalization, but how can I implement that for such rules:

```
1   {}                            => {262012} 0.10813429 0.1081343   1.000000
2   {}                            => {211050} 0.11001969 0.1100197   1.000000
3   {}                            => {275001} 0.13768607 0.1376861   1.000000
4   {}                            => {274001} 0.16672743 0.1667274   1.000000
5   {}                            => {121001} 0.44729742 0.4472974   1.000000
6   {275006}                      => {211050} 0.05095780 0.8717035   7.923159
7   {211050}                      => {275006} 0.05095780 0.4631699   7.923159
8   {275006}                      => {274001} 0.05197863 0.8891661   5.333052
9   {274001}                      => {275006} 0.05197863 0.3117581   5.333052
10  {231050}                      => {231051} 0.06063479 1.0000000  16.492183
11  {231051}                      => {231050} 0.06063479 1.0000000  16.492183
12  {231050}                      => {275001} 0.05490568 0.9055145   6.576661
13  {275001}                      => {231050} 0.05490568 0.3987744   6.576661
14  {231050}                      => {274001} 0.06063479 1.0000000   5.997813
15  {274001}                      => {231050} 0.06063479 0.3636761   5.997813
16  {231050}                      => {121001} 0.05639525 0.9300807   2.079334
17  {121001}                      => {231050} 0.05639525 0.1260800   2.079334
...
```

Does any one do something like this?